# Crowdfunding total backers - counter

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a crowdfunding website using this theme http://demo.astoundify.com/switcher/?theme=fundify .
If you see the footer, it has some information about the money that was earned, and about the total number of campaigns.

I was trying to change this, I don't want the information about how much money was earned but I want to put the total number of backers for all of the campaigns.

I already tried to add this:

```
<?php echo $campaign->backers_count(); ?>
<?php echo _nx( 'Backer', 'Backers', $campaign->backers_count(), 'number of backers for campaign', 'fundify' ); ?>
```

But it was no good.

I bought this theme and I already tried to ask in the support forum but their solution is to gather the number of backers and insert it manually on the footer.

Can I generate some kind of code that gives me the total number of backers?

Comment: You can copy and paste the function that get the total money earned and rename it to beckers and change the query to get the beckers instead. Unhappily without seeing how the SQL structure is we can't help you with the information you have provided so far and it seems this is for WordPress? You should add that to the tag.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code it's impossible to answer (see [ask]). And nobody is going to buy, or download, or install, the theme just to help you. Anyway, Prix suggestion is spot on.